# Excel VBA: how to apply code when it finds text in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code, modified by @FreeMan from one of my previous questions. I want to find the text "Hours" in any row in the worksheet. Then, apply the code to the column containing that text. This code is supposed to do that, but it does not work for me for some reason. I would really appreciate your help with this. Thank you in advance.

```
Sub CeldasinInfo()

Dim i As Long, r As Range, coltoSearch As String
Dim Result as String
Dim ErrCount as integer

ErrCount = 0
coltoSearch = "A"
coltoSearch = Range("1:1").find(What:="Hours", LookIn:=xlValues,     LookAt:=xlWhole).Column

Result = "No Value in:" & vbcrlf
For i = 1 To Range(coltoSearch & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set r = Range(coltoSearch & i)
If Len(r.Value) = 0 Then
     r.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 ' Red
      r.Select
      MsgBox "No Value, in " & r.Address
      Result = Result & r.Address & vbcrlf
      ErrCount = ErrCount + 1
      if ErrCount Mod 10 = 0 then    'change to 15 or 20 or whatever works well
        MsgBox Result
        Result = "No Value in:" & vbcrlf
      End If
      Sheets("Results").Range("A" & Sheets("Results").Range("A" &   Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Offset(1, 0).Formula = r.Address
End If
Next

If ErrCount > 0 then
MsgBox "There were " & ErrCount & " errors detected." & vbcrlf & result
else
MsgBox "No errors detected"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is that your `coltoSearch` variable will always be a number or nothing according to your code, but you're using it like it will be a letter.

Comment: Should `r` be a range, or perhaps instead a string? `Dim r as String` and then `r = Cells(i,coltosearch).Value`?  What is NOT happening when you say "...it does not work for me."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change these two lines of code:

```
For i = 1 To Range(coltoSearch & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set r = Range(coltoSearch & i)
```

to:

```
For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, coltoSearch).End(xlUp).Row
Set r = Cells(i, coltoSearch)
```

Remove line: `coltoSearch = "A"`

`coltoSearch` should be an integer.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response but I still get error 400.

Comment: What is the error text and on what line does the error occur?

Comment: The message box for the error just shows the number 400. That's all.

Comment: And which line generates the error?  What happens if you take out the `r.Select` line?

Comment: Still shows me the same error if I remove r.Select line. Did you try the code at your end and it worked?

Comment: It work now! I did not see your modifications above!, Thank you! :)